# How to hide IOS safari address bar on scroll?

Tags: angular, typescript, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am building a PWA and finding it difficult to hide the IOS safari navbar (address bar) on scrolling, I tried all the solution available but unfortunately, nothing helped. Is there any way to hide the address bar on scrolling for iPhone (IOS 7+) safari?

## header.scss

```
display: flex;
padding: 0 16px;
width: 100%;
align-items: center;
color: white;
position: absolute;
background-color: #353f50;
top: 0;
height: 64px;
z-index: 2;
```

## footer.scss

````
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;```

router-outlet content has height: calc(100vh-64px)

Current output:
![Current](https://i.imgur.com/mapbX0i.jpg)

Expected:
![Expected](https://i.imgur.com/eCbCUUI.jpg)
````

Answer (score 2):

Add this meta tag to the head of index.html

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: Yes, i added this, and this is only helpful if the user presses add to home screen from browser

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented a PWA, you can specify how it should be rendered in the browser by setting the `display` property in the web manifest file.

I wrote an article explaining in details the [different display values](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa#display) and how the applications will look like.

In your case, I would use `display: standalone` as it will remove the address bar and open the application in a separate window (not the same one used by the browser).

The layout would be like the following (note the absence of address bar):

[image]

If this would not work, as iOS has terrible PWA support, you can:

1. Add `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` tag

or

2. Use the `pwacompat` [library](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/pwacompat)

Comment: Tried everything, still the same

Comment: If you access the browser Dev tools, can you see that the service worker is properly installed and the web manifest doesn't have any warnings?

Comment: Nope, nothing. It works perfectly if I add to home screen